# Delaying window.open inside click event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, window.open

For some days now I've been trying (without success) to open new window with delay without Chrome blocking it most of the time. Delay is crucial for my task, because some animation must take place before window is opened and I can not afford browsers to block new tabs from opening. Here is sample from my code:

```
element.on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this),
        url = self[0].href;

    window.setTimeout(function(){
        window.open(url);
    }, 1000);
});
```

element is jQuery object (anchor element to be more precise). I have noticed that I have bigger success rate if I pass string directly like this

```
window.open("http://example.com");
```

I've tried this solution in Explorer(no problem), Chrome(problem), Firefox(no problem) and Opera(problem). I am loosing my mind, because I've tried everything I can remember. Synchronous ajax calls, artificially triggering click, creating fake anchor elements and artificially triggering click event. Nothing works fine. 
Bonus question (in case someone knows how to solve problem): is there a way to call window.open anytime & anywhere from code?

Comment: could you provide us a fiddle, or code by which we could reproduce the issue? What about calling `window.open` once animation finished it's execution?

Comment: I have just checked ur code with this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/xeoctj2p/1/, the problem I am getting is, the pop-up blocker stops it, may be you must inform user to allow pop-ups for your site.

Comment: @code-jaff: Of course I've tried this. It is even worse. I get popup blocker each time window.open is executed and on each browser. mido22: I don't want to solve problem like that. In worse case scenario I will use window.location.href, but even that has its own disadvantages. It does not reload window instantaneously that is the biggest problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me in Chrome http://jsbin.com/wuqopukayuwi/4/

```
var $element = $('#link');


$element.on('click', function () {

   var url= $(this).attr('href');

   window.setTimeout(function(){

     var windowObjRef = window.open(url);

     console.log(windowObjRef);

  }, 2000);

});
```

Things to check:

- Obviously, double check you've enabled popups for your domain in Chrome (it prompts you the first time it tries to pop up a new window
- It's because Chrome expects to be able to access that window again programatically, so wants you to declare the response to the method as a variable. At least, that's how I got it working...

Comment: IMPORTANT!!! window does not open window with delay. It opens it instantly, because you forgot to prevent default behavior (opening link)!!!! Include e.preventDefault like I did: http://jsbin.com/yugugoyobega/1

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know how long the animation runs then you sleep for number of seconds
Add sleep(), msleep() and usleep() to Node.js, via a C++ binding.

This is mainly useful for debugging.

These calls will block execution of all JavaScript by halting Node.js' event loop!

Usage

```
`var sleep = require('sleep');
sleep.sleep(n): sleep for n seconds
sleep.msleep(n): sleep for n miliseconds
sleep.usleep(n): sleep for n microseconds (1 second is 1000000 
microseconds)`
```